# Adding a printer using vbscript ... expected end of statement

Tags: printing, vbscript

Even though I appear to write it as pretty much all the examples on the web, I still have this error.
Here, take a look... https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcVeC.png

My code is as follows (in case you didn't take a look):

```
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs" -a -r "C70 PS Driver" -h 13.226.51.135 -o raw -n 9200
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -a -v 3 -m "Xerox Color C70 PS" -i "C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf\x2GITHP.inf" -h "C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf"
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "Xerox Color C70 PS" -m "Xerox Color C70 PS" -r "C70 PS Driver"
```

The error is at line 1, and says:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Antoine\AppData\Local\Adersoft\VbsEdit\Temp\MMNPNCCZ.vbs(1, 78) Microsoft VBScript >compilation error: Expected end of statement
>
> ***** script completed - exit code: 1 *****

Edit: Here's the content of the file (C:\Users\Antoine\AppData\Local\Adersoft\VbsEdit\Temp\MMNPNCCZ.vbs)

```
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs" -a -r "C70 PS Driver" -h 13.226.51.135 -o raw -n 9200
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -a -v 3 -m "Xerox Color C70 PS" -i "C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf\x2GITHP.inf" -h "C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf"
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "Xerox Color C70 PS" -m "Xerox Color C70 PS" -r "C70 PS Driver"
```

I have to say, its my first time trying to script this, so yes, I'm new to this.
In any case, all comments are welcomed.

Thank you,

Comment: The syntax/compile time error is in prnport.vbs (or MMNPNCCZ.vbs); you need to publish that.

Comment: You are trying to feed command interpreter code to cscript.exe. Use the cscript button to run **VBScript** code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `MMNPNCCZ.vbs` to `MMNPNCCZ.bat`. You can't run commands from VBScript like that.

```
@echo off
rem MMNPNCCZ.bat

cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs" -a -r "C70 PS Driver" -h 13.226.51.135 -o raw -n 9200
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -a -v 3 -m "Xerox Color C70 PS" -i "C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf\x2GITHP.inf" -h "C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf"
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "Xerox Color C70 PS" -m "Xerox Color C70 PS" -r "C70 PS Driver"
```

If you must do it in VBScript you'd need something like this:

```
' MMNPNCCZ.vbs

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "cscript ""C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs"" -a -r ""C70 PS Driver"" -h 13.226.51.135 -o raw -n 9200", 0, True
sh.Run "cscript ""C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs"" -a -v 3 -m ""Xerox Color C70 PS"" -i ""C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf\x2GITHP.inf"" -h ""C:\Xerox_C70_2014_11\XCC70_5.382.4.0_PS_x64_Driver.inf""", 0, True
sh.Run "cscript ""C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs"" -a -p ""Xerox Color C70 PS"" -m ""Xerox Color C70 PS"" -r ""C70 PS Driver""", 0, True
```

Comment: I have a mix of W7x64 and W8.1x64. Which way would you recommend? And thank you! :)

Comment: @Xeroidian If you're just running the 3 commands you showed: use a batch-file. You could also use PowerShell, which allows you to run external commands in almost the same way batch does.

Comment: It didn't work. I tried copying verbatim your code and making it a .bat and running that as admin no result.  Wish I could invite you in a logmein and email you a starbucks afterwords.

Comment: @Xeroidian The code sample from my answer is for running the script as a `.vbs`, which I would not recommend in your case. Put the code from your question in a `.bat` and it should work (added sample to my answer for clarification). If it still doesn't: try running it in a 32-bit interpreter (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CMD.exe`). If *that* also doesn't work: do you get an error? If so: put the error message in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much Ansgar. It worked like a charm. I'll further my education concerning the basics of bat and vbs etc. Much appreciated!